# Remove duplicates from result set using javax.persistence.criteria by data prorety

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I need to return the latest data. Date fields are called `dateModified`. Since the old data is not deleted in any way, there are a lot of similar records, they differ only in the `dateModified` field. The current query returns all records, and I need only the most recent in the field `dateModified`.

```
    public List<SomeDto> search(SearchDto criteria) {
            final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            final CriteriaQuery<SomeDto> query = cb.createQuery(SomeDto.class);
            final Root<SomeModel> root = query.from(SomeModel.class);
            query.multiselect(
                 root.get(ID),
                 root.get(SOME_ENTERNAL_ID),
                 root.get(SOME_NAME_ID));
                 query.where(createPredicates(cb, query, root, criteria));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to order all the results in descending order and get the first result, something like this:

```
public List<SomeDto> search(SearchDto criteria) {
            final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            final CriteriaQuery<SomeDto> query = cb.createQuery(SomeDto.class);
            final Root<SomeModel> root = query.from(SomeModel.class);
            query.multiselect(
                 root.get(ID),
                 root.get(SOME_ENTERNAL_ID),
                 root.get(SOME_NAME_ID));
                 query.where(createPredicates(cb, query, root, criteria))
                      .orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("dateModified")));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query)
                        .setFirstResult(0)
                        .setMaxResults(1)
                        .getResultList();
}
```

The method will return a list with one element which has the most recent dateModified.